# adding a control to a custom cell view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting really frustrated trying to solve this problem i tried implementing it in many many ways but no solution. I have a UIStepper in a custom cell and i want to change a value on the cell. Everything works fine expect when i scroll around the tableView the values from the UIStepper changes from one cell to another. Please help here are my screen shoots.
[Link to tableview implementation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/StuffRandom/Random/Screen+Shot+2014-04-22+at+5.18.23+PM.png) and [link to cell implementation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/StuffRandom/Random/Screen+Shot+2014-04-22+at+5.18.52+PM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to store the stepper value inside each individual cell. That's not going to work because cells are reused; the cell that you now see in row 2 may reappear in row 20 when the user scrolls.

That is why you must store the value for the stepper in the *model* (your data) on a row-by-row basis, so that you can set it freshly and correctly for that row every single time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

This, in turn, means that as the user steps the stepper, its `valueChanged` is going to need to talk *to the table view data source* so that the model can be updated ("the stepper value for row 5 has just been changed to 3") and maintained in the model.

Comment: Thanks for replying this is how i fixed it. link to table view https://s3.amazonaws.com/StuffRandom/Random/Screen+Shot+2014-04-23+at+10.27.32+AM.png and link to cell https://s3.amazonaws.com/StuffRandom/Random/Screen+Shot+2014-04-23+at+10.27.08+AM.png