# Multiple UICollectionView in a UITableView are intertwined in scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, nested-lists

I am totally new to iOS development, so my problem might be a noob question but I have no clue how to make my `UICollectionViews` scroll separately from each other. When I scroll my top `UICollectionView`, scroll down, my other `UICollectionView` is also scrolled without touching it.

The `UICollectionView` is configured to scroll horizontally. What I want to achieve is something like Netflix has done. With the user being able to scroll horizontally, while the list of items is shown horizontally. So far everything works, except the scrolling of one list makes the other scrolls too when they are redrawn (I guess, since I can only see it happen on lists that are not yet shown on the device.)

I hope I have described my problem properly, might you be missing some information to help me solve this I am of course happy to provide.

So my `UITableController` looks like this:

```
class MoviesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let categories = ["In theaters", "Popular", "Upcoming", "Top rated"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "232637")
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "232637")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.rowHeight = 332;
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 42;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
    view.tintColor = UIColor.init(hex: "232637")
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.init(hex: "ff5959")
}
```

}

my `UITableViewCell` looks like this:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let imageNames = //Some filler data
let gameNames  = //Some filler data

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "232637")
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 32,right: 0)
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageNames.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCell
    //cell.imageView.imageFromURL(urlString: imageNames[indexPath.row])

    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img-logo"))
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    image.frame = cell.containerView.bounds
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    image.clipsToBounds = true;
    image.imageFromURL(urlString: imageNames[indexPath.row])
    cell.containerView.addSubview(image)
    cell.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "232637")

    return cell
}
```

}

And my `UICollectionViewCell` looks like this:

```
class MovieCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
```

}

My Views look like this:

[image: My views looks like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are failing to take into account the fact that cells (table view cells as well as collection view cells) are *reused*. Thus, if a table view contains a collection view and you scroll that collection view and then you scroll the table view, the table view cell is reused in a new row and the previously scrolled collection view inside it remains scrolled to where you put it previously. If that's not what you want, it's up to you to reset the scroll position of the collection view when you discover that the cell is being reused.

What gave me a clue that you might be not be understanding cell reuse is this line:

```
 cell.containerView.addSubview(image)
```

That's wrong, because you're doing it even if the cell is reused, meaning that some of your cells will end up with dozens of image views overlaying one another, slowing things down and eventually perhaps causing you to run out of memory. That's not the problem you asked about, but it is a sign that you are not aware of the implications of cell reuse.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right that I did not take this into account. I fixed most parts of the structure now. But I fail to find any possible solutions to keep the scrolling position of the rows that have been scrolled and let others start at the start of their list. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Like everything else about a row, that needs to be part of your model data

Comment: I still have no clue and cannot find any useful examples/tutorials. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be mysterious. I'm just suggesting that "how far is the collection view scrolled in this row" is just like "does the image view appear in this row" in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35873367/341994) question, or "the stepper value for this row" in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23230753/341994) one, or "did the user set the UISwitch in this row" in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23595189/341994) one. Whatever the user does in a row must be _stored_ in your data model so that it can be restored whenever a cell is requested for that row.

Comment: E.g. in this simple example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p809peopleGroups/ch36p1066peopleGroups/PeopleLister.swift we have editable text fields in each cell, so I make the view controller the delegate of the text fields so I can store the user's edits in the model (i.e. `self.people`, see `textFieldDidEndEditing`). I'm just suggesting that the user scrolling the collection view in a row of your table might be like that: a user setting pertaining to _that row_ that you might need to record in the data model and restore in `cellForRow`.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. thank you very much for all the help you have given.